# esp8266 wifi/ read serial data with python

Tags: esp8266, python

I'm trying to read some serial (ADC) data from my esp8266 nodeMCU v3 over wifi using python.
I connected the esp on my local wifi and set it with fixed local IP using arduino IDE, but I couldn't find a way to extract the data using Python.
In a normal case, I just type in my python code the COM Port number and the Baudrate and just read. But with Wifi I counld not find a simple solution.
any Ideas ?
Thanks

Comment: There is no simple Serial via Wifi. You can look into websockets. I think that would be the way to transmit the data over the wifi network

Comment: You can run an httpserver on the esp and request desired data via wifi. Here's a tutorial https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp8266-web-server-with-arduino-ide/

Comment: A basic TCP connection via WiFiClient would be easier than web sockets or an HTTP server, and would provide a reliable byte stream.